# importing tyhe csv file in ios sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, csv

In my app, I am trying to import the csv files as follow:

```
NSError *error;
    NSString *path1=[[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:CSVPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@",path1);
    NSArray *messArr=[path1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    NSLog(@"%@",messArr);
```

**Question:**
When i try to log the array, it gives the last column values with many spaces like as follow:

**Path1:** student_name,gender,email_id

test1,male,a

test2,male,b

test3,male3,c

**messArr:**

(
    "student_name,gender,email_id

",

```
"test1,male,a
```

",

```
"test2,male,b
```

",

```
"test3,male3,c"
```

)

Here i got the count is 4 but can't able to remove spaces.

So, I can't able to remove spaces from the messArr.
Why this happen? I don't know.
Help me to solve this problem.

i think there is a problem with which encoding scheme you used when you creating the csv file.

Thank you,

Comment: Can you remove every space and enter in the result strings or do you have strings like `"asdf dfg, asdf, ghjk"` (where the first part of the string is two words)?

Answer (score 1):

Please use CSV Parser available on Github repository.

[Use CSV parser for Objective-C](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of \n. if you dont want it then remove this line

`NSArray *messArr=[path1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];`

for showing line iterate your array in `for` loop, & hardcode the `\n` in the code

```
for(int i=0; i<[messArr count];i++)
{
NSLog(@"%@\n",[messArr objectAtindex:i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But then how can i separate the rows from csv file?

Comment: i think there is a problem with which encoding scheme you used when you creating the csv file.

Comment: yes, it prints exactly same i want but how can I take into this array?

Comment: It is still coming with newline character when i try to take into the new array. I tried your code but not working. As you see above in my code, the last values "test3,male3,c" is fetch perfectly but except last value the others have the spaces& new line.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the spaces

by using this meted on each object of messier

```
NSString *str=[[messArr objectAtIndex:index] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
```

use this str for your purpose.

Comment: i think there is a problem with which encoding scheme you used when you creating the csv file.

Comment: @user1896921 whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet this is a characerSet which having white spaces and newline chars. you need to use the same line as per your logic of accessing array's subscripted variables.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried your code but not working. As you see above in my code, the last values `"test3,male3,c"` is fetch perfectly but except last value the others have the spaces& new line.